# Remove white space between divs when using jinja2

Tags: python, css, html

So I get that white spaces are created if two inline divs are next to each other with a new line.
But my problem is that I have a bunch of jinja 2 code so I can't just put the divs on the same line.

I want to put `divs` inline so that they appear next to each other without space in between them. My layout is dynamically generated. Here is what it looks like now[image]

The container is `900px` wide so I tried to make each data div to be `300px` so I can have 3 fields per row.

This is what I would like it to look like:
[image]

Here is the code for the title and the fields:

```
HTML/Jinja2

        <div class="section">

            <div class="sectionTitle">
                <label class="print_h3">{{ title }} Info</label><br />
            </div>

            <div class="print_dataDiv">
                <label class="print_inputBoxLabels">Model</label>
                <select name="model" class="print_inputBoxes">
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="print_dataDiv">
                <label class="print_inputBoxLabels">Substation</label>
                <select name="substation" class="print_inputBoxes">
                </select>
            </div>
            {% for field in field_list %}
                <div class="print_dataDiv">
                    <label class="print_inputBoxLabels">{{field.field_name}}</label>
                    <input class="print_inputBoxes" name="field_{{field.field_id}}_{{field.device_id}}" value="{{field.field_value}}" type="input">
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

CSS(in order as they appear in the code):
.section{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border: solid 1px;
}
.sectionTitle{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
    border: solid 1px;
    background: #B3B3B3;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    //margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.print_dataDiv {
    height: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 2px;
}
.print_inputBoxLabels{
    width: 140px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
    font-size: 80%;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
.print_inputBoxes{
    width: 130px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    outline:none;
}
```

EDIT: here is a bigger example of my jinja2 code that prevents lining the divs up on the same line

```
{% for inspection in data.inspections %}
                                <div class="print_dataDiv">
                                    <label class="print_inputBoxLabels">{{ inspection.insName }}</label>
                                    {% if inspection.statusDict|length > 0 %}
                                        <select class="print_inputBoxes" name="inspection_{{ inspection.insID }}_{{ inspection.inspectionID }}">
                                            {% for key, value in inspection.statusDict.iteritems() %}
                                                {% if key == inspection.value %}
                                                    <option selected="selected" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
                                                {% else %}
                                                    <option value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
                                                {% endif %}
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        </select>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <input type="text" class="print_inputBoxes" name="inspection_{{ inspection.insID }}_{{ inspection.inspectionID }}" value="{{inspection.value}}">
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Try this http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: thanks, I believe I had read this article but I probably skimmed over it too fast and missed a few key pieces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for field in field_list %}<!--
        --><div class="print_dataDiv">
                <label class="print_inputBoxLabels">{{field.field_name}}</label>
                <input class="print_inputBoxes" name="field_{{field.field_id}}_{{field.device_id}}" value="{{field.field_value}}" type="input">
            </div><!--
-->{% endfor %}
```

Alternatively, give `font-size:0` to the parent.

Comment: It just seems to get rid of my labels then

Comment: Yeah. But then you need to define the font-size for each of the children of .section.

Comment: Ah I see, well I tried it but still doesn't seem to take the gap away, I'll try and do the html comment trick

Comment: @john Great! Faced the similar issue few days back

Comment: Alternatively use `{#\n#}`.

Answer (score 2):

`for` blocks are easy... unfortunately not all block expressions work with this

```
{% for field in field_list -%}
    <div>...</div>
{%- endfor %}
```

http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#whitespace-control

> You can also strip whitespace in templates by hand. If you add a minus sign (-) to the start or end of a block (e.g. a For tag), a comment, or a variable expression, the whitespaces before or after that block will be removed

Comment: Alternatively set env `trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True`. https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/api/#jinja2.Environment